# jQuery Rotate Image Not On Center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, rotation

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to rotate an image on a particular point.

I've been using http://jsfiddle.net/YKj5D/ as an example; which works perfectly when wanting to rotate an image from its center point.

However, using the example above, i wanted to rotate the image around the letter G, how could this be achieved?

Current code:

```
function rotateGearStick()
{
var rotation = function (){
       $("#gear-stick").rotate({
          angle:0, 
          animateTo:110, 
       });
    }
    rotation();
}
```

Where gear-stick is the ID of my image.

I'm attempting to create an rev counter dial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/YKj5D/1988/

```
#image{
    margin:100px;
    padding-left:170px; /* <----- */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't expect such an easy fix! Could you explain how the CSS advised above is achieving this? And would it differ if say i wanted to rotate on the letter E?

Comment: @OamPsy well, the trick should be easy to spot, managing `padding` we're actually adding / substracting some "invisible" element area that will make the element wider, that way we're translating the rotational center. One issue might be using background colors, than I suggest using `transform-origin`

Answer (score 1):

I find this a lot more cleaner fix.

```
#image{
    -webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin:0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin:0px 0px;
    transform-origin:0px 0px; //px or percent whichever you prefer
}
```

Just change the origin values to whatever suits your needs and it will rotate about that origin.

Answer (score 1):

Recent version of jQueryRotate handles changing center of rotation cross-browse. Using padding-only solution will not work for a fallbacks to CANVAS/VML. Please check http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com

Answer (score 1):

The http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com (suggested by Wilq32 in above post) documentation says adding the "center" attribute as shown below. It takes a array of length 2 of absolute pixel position or percentage. I.e. `center: ["150px", "100px"]` OR `center: ["60%", "50%"]`

```
var rotation = function (){
  $("#image").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      center: ["150px", "100px"], 
      callback: rotation
  });
}

rotation();
```